# I want to schedule a task to run a batch file on weekly basis using Java code

Tags: java

Is there any way to write a java code for the same i.e. scheduler code to execute the batch file.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely your OS supports this already and is a better choice for doing this. In Windows its called Scheduled Tasks and in Unix its cron.

You can use Quartz in Java, but I would try the OS support first.

Answer (score 0):

for Win OS is easier to use "Task Scheduler"

br